# Do arbitrary products commute with coproducts in abelian categories

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

In an abelian category, finite products and coproducts coincide, but arbitrary products and coproducts might not: for example in **Ab**, the category of abelian groups, the elements of an infinite product are given by arbitrary tuples of elements from each factor, whereas the elements of an infinite coproduct are given by tuples with only finitely many nonzero entries.

On the other hand, I think that there should still be a canonical isomorphism $\prod_i (A_i \oplus B_i) \cong (\prod_i A_i) \oplus (\prod_i B_i)$. In abelian groups, this isomorphism should take the tuple $(... (a_i, b_i), (a_{i + 1}, b_{i+1}),...)$ to $((..., a_i, a_{i+1},...), (..., b_i, b_{i+1}, ...))$, but I'm having trouble giving a proof using universal properties.

What's tripping me up is that $P_1 = \prod_i (A_i \oplus B_i)$ has the following universal property: a map *into* $P_1$ is defined by a choice of map to each $A_i$ and each $B_i$; while the universal property of $P_2 = (\prod_i A_i) \oplus (\prod_i B_i)$ says that a map *out* of $P_2$ is given by a choice of map to each $A_i$ and each $B_i$. So I can get a canonical map from $P_2$ to $P_1$, but I'm not sure how I know that this map is an isomorphism.

Can someone give me a hand with the abstract proof for a generic abelian category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since finite products and coproducts coincide, the isomorphism you want amounts to $\prod_i(A_i\times B_i)\cong (\prod_iA_i) \times(\prod_iB_i)$ Now both sides are products of the same factors, so your proposed isomorphism works.

Comment: Of course! Thanks!

Comment: This argument made essential use  of the fact that you were asking about **finite** coproducts. The analogous statement with infinite coproducts is false.